# Is it possible to Set Image to paint object instead of color?

Tags: android, view, paint, rect

```
 Paint mPaint = new Paint();
 mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
 mPaint.setColor(Color.Red);
 canvas.drawRect(mRedPaddleRect, mPaint);
```

Here, mRedPaddleRect is a Rectangle formed using Rect and instead of setting It a color I want set an Image.

How can this be done?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: do u  want the image to be added to the canvas right ??

Comment: Not the entire canvas but to the Rect object I have created.

Answer (score 7):

That is how I did it, I could not believe it was that easy

```
       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.racquet);
       canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, mRedPaddleRect, mPaint);
```

Hopefully this would help out others too.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(result);
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = workingBitmap
            .copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
```

**Put you paint code here**

```
        Paint paint = new Paint();

    paint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color)); // Text

        paint.setStrokeWidth(12); // Text Size
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)); // Text
                                                                                // Overlapping
                                                                                // Pattern
        // some more settings...

        canvas.drawBitmap(mutableBitmap, RECTsrc, RECTdst, paint);
```

Try something like this hope this helps

Comment: Ok, Thanks ! Will try this out, but where shall I set the path for the image i.e to be displayed( which is being stored in Drawable of Resource )?

Comment: i hope the answer helped

Comment: that is how I did it and couldn't believe it was that easy.. Thanks for dropping by. (y)
In the process I learned many great things of Views and canvas. :)